# library not found for -lGIPNSURL+FIFE clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1

Tags: ios, iphone, ios9.1

When I integrate `GoogleSingIn` or `GoogleCloudMessage` in my Project via Pod file i'm facing this issue.

> issue -> ld: library not found for -lGIPNSURL+FIFE clang: error:
>   linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)